# jQuery .on('click') issues when using position absolute

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to create a website with a popup element with a dark backdrop and then, when you click the backdrop it fades away. At the moment I have it basically working **but** when clicking **within** the popup not just the backdrop, it still fades away.

How would I fix this? [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3gc22700/)

**The section of HTML I am trying to fix:**

```
<div class="popup-container" data-reference="sign-in">
    <div class="sign-in">
        <h1>Sign In</h1>
        <div class="popup-content-container">
        <form class="sign-in" method="post" action="./action.php">
            <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username" /><br />
            <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" /><br />
            <input type="submit" value="Sign In" /><br />
        </form>
        <div class="footer">
            <a href="#">Forgotten Username?</a> <a href="#">Forgotten Username?</a><br />
            <a href="#">Don't Have an Account?</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Current jQuery:**

```
$('div.popup-container').on('click', function() {
    $(this).fadeOut();
});
```

**Current CSS, for the section of HTML:**

```
div.popup-container {
    position:absolute;
    margin:auto auto;
    top:0;bottom:0;
    left:0;right:0;
    background:rgba(0,0,0,0.5);

    z-index:101;
}
    div.popup-container:hover {
        cursor:pointer;
    }
/*----  Sign In ----*/
div.sign-in {
    width:400px;
    height:300px;
    position:absolute;
    margin:auto auto;
    top:0;bottom:0;
    left:0;right:0;
    background:#FFF;
    border:solid 1px #CCC;
    border-radius:5px;

    z-index:111;
}
    div.sign-in:hover {
        cursor:default;
    }
    div.sign-in > h1 {
        display:block;
        padding:15px 0;
        border-bottom:solid 1px #CCC;
        text-align:center;
    }
    div.sign-in > div.popup-content-container {
        height:calc(100% - 98px);
        position:relative;
        padding:15px;
    }
    div.sign-in > div.popup-content-container > form.sign-in {
        height:calc(102px + 34px);
        position:absolute;
        margin:auto auto;
        top:0;bottom:0;
        left:0;right:0;
        text-align:center;
    }
        div.sign-in > div.popup-content-container > form.sign-in > input[type=text],
        div.sign-in > div.popup-content-container > form.sign-in > input[type=password],
        div.sign-in > div.popup-content-container > form.sign-in > input[type=submit] {
            width:75%;
            margin-bottom:5px;
            padding:5px;
            background:#FFF;
            border:solid 1px #CCC;
            border-radius:5px;

            outline:none;   
        }
        div.sign-in > div.popup-content-container > form.sign-in > input[type=submit]:hover {
            background:rgba(0,0,0,0.05);
        }
        div.sign-in > div.popup-content-container > div.footer {
            position:absolute;
            margin:auto auto;
            top:auto;bottom:15px;
            left:0;right:0;
            color:rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
            text-align:center;
        }
```

**tl;dr**: why does my `.on('click')` trigger inside the popup as well as outside of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution could be:

```
$('div.popup-container').on('click', function() {
    $(this).fadeOut();
});

$('div.sign-in').on('click', function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

This will stop the child elements automatically triggering any click event attached to the parent (popup-container) element.

More about `event.stopPropagation()` [**here**](https://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/).

[**jsFiddle here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/3gc22700/1/)

Comment: Thanks friend! This'll do just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try out this code in your jquery file:

```
$(document).on('click','div.popup-container' ,function() {
   $(this).fadeOut();
});
```